Какой API карт подойдет для поиска расстояния между двумя точками на карте по дорогам?
По сути нужно взять значения latitude и longitude на двух точках карты и определить расстояние между ними по дорогам.
Какой, желательно бесплатный API карт подойдет для этой задачи?
Программа написана на платформе Xamarin, по этому требуется Android совместимый API.

расстояние по дорогам это проложить маршрут называется.

мне не маршрут нужен, мне не требуется графический интерфейс карты друг мой, мне нужно расстояние по дорогам

Маршрут это набор данных из точек с координатами, описывающими путь по дорогам. Если последовательно посчитать и просуммировать расстояние между соседними точками, получится ответ на ваш вопрос.

@aepot все же ТС прав, маршрут это уже лишняя сущность для его задачи. Это примерно как предлагать сначала пройти пешком маршрут, потом получить трек, а потом подсчитать его длину )

Подойдёт OpenStreetMap, (NuGet - OsmSharp)
